# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Problem is occurring here:

```
@Html.DropDownList("KategoriId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.KategoriId = new SelectList(db.Kategoris, "KategoriId", "KategoriAdi");
     return View();
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KategoriId, "KategoriId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("KategoriId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KategoriId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you explain your question further? I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Write your `@Html.DropDownList()` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("KategoriId", ViewBag.KategoriId as SelectList,"Select Ketegory Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Type Casting ViewBag to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in CSHTML:

CSHTML Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("your_key", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.KategoriId, "--Select Any--", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Controller code:

```
IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in db.Kategoris.ToList())
{
  SelectListItem sellist = new SelectListItem();
  sellist.Value = item.code.ToString();
  sellist.Text = item.name;
  items.Add(sellist);
}
ViewBag.KategoriId = items; // at the end this item should be list of `SelectListItem`
```